# Transition to simple javascript slideshow

Tags: javascript, image, slideshow, transition

Hey guys I am having some trouble finding a simple way to add a transition to a very basic javascript image slide show:

```
//variable that will increment through the images
var step=1
var whichimage=1
function slideit(){
    //if browser does not support the image object, exit.
    if (!document.images)
        return
    document.images.slide.src=eval('image'+step+'.src')
    whichimage=step
    if (step<3)
        step++
    else
        step=1
    //call function 'slideit()' every 5 seconds
    setTimeout('slideit()',5000)
}
slideit()
function slidelink(){
    if (whichimage==1)
        window.location='page1.php'
    else if (whichimage==2)
        window.location='page1.php'
    else if (whichimage==3)
        window.location='index.php'
}
```

How can i add in a fade or swipe transition?

Comment: Are you intentionally avoiding jQuery? (and if so, why?)

Comment: Are you intentionally avoiding `;` and `switch`? :)

Comment: You have a lot of formatting issues with your code, namely the missing closing semicolons... Though to answer your question there is no "simple" way to add transitions. You'll either need to use an animation library (such as the suggested jQuery and jQuery UI), or write your own. Writing your own will not be simple.

Comment: I am not avoiding the use of jQuery I just had not considered it, I am creating a website which I would like to be coded without. I am still an amateur with javascript so I would like to get better. didn't consider a switch, cause it worked. I wrote it fairly quickly so forgot ";"

Comment: While I understand (and appreciate) the philosophy to avoid libraries when possible, this is typically a case where you would put a lot of time and effort into a functionnality that exists in a library broadly used (and stable), with no guarantee of success